# Access Query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have an Access Database with a few tables, among them Order, OrderDetails and Client.

- Order (OrderID, TimeStamp, FKEmployeeID, FKClientID, OrderStatus, Comments)
- OrderDetails (OrderDetailsID, FKOrderID, FKProductID, Quantity, Cost, Total Cost)
- Client (ClientID, Name)

I'm trying to build a query where I can get the total orders that a client has made and the total Items.

Example:

```
Customer,  Total Orders,  Total Items
John,          5,              15
Alex,          2,              30
Ana,           1,              3
```

Whenever I try to make a query Total Orders and Total Items give me the same number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported even by ms access:

```
SELECT c.Name,  
(select count(*) 
 from Orders o 
 where o. FKClientID = C.ClientID) as [Total Orders],
(select sum(Quantity) as Items 
 from OrderDetails od 
 inner join Order o on o.OrderID = od.FKOrderID
 where o.FKClientId = C.ClientID) as [Total Items]
from Client c;
```

Comment: This works but is bringing me all the clients even if they don't have any orders made. Would it be possible for it to bring me only the clients that have orders? I have seen in other places where they say that ms-access doesn't support the count distinct function.

Comment: You don't need distinct here. You can simply add a where clause to filter out clients with no orders: ... from Client c where exists (select * from Order where c.ClientId = Order.FKClientID)

Comment: I would like to make this query into a report and be able to filter by the timestamp date so that it brings me orders made from x date to y date. Wouldnt the where clause cause conflict?

Comment: @Ans, nope it wouldn't cause conflict you can add the clause in your where with "and" - remember you may need to add that to multiple places based on your needs (you may even might want to base your on Order rather than Client).

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. Could you guide me as how I could add the field timestamp and OrderStatus to the query so I could later filter by it on the report. I have some trouble understanding the syntax of how to add fields to complex queries when they have nested selects etc.

Comment: :( OK. I will add another answer giving sample from Northwind.mdb sample database (almost the same structure).

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution (clients without orders are left out hereby):

```
SELECT Client.[Name], 
       Count(myTotalItems.OrderID) As TotalOrders, 
       Sum(myTotalItems.TotalItems) As TotalItems
FROM Client,
    (SELECT First([Order].OrderID) As OrderID, 
            First([Order].FKClientID) As 
            ClientID, 
            Count(OrderDetails.OrderDetailsID) As TotalItems 
     FROM [Order], OrderDetails 
     WHERE OrderDetails.FKOrderID like [Order].OrderID
     GROUP BY [Order].OrderID) As myTotalItems 
WHERE myTotalItems.ClientID like Client.ClientID 
GROUP BY Client.[Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  You can do this with two aggregations:

```
SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(*) As NumOrders, SUM(o.NumItems) As NumItems
FROM Client as c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT o.OrderID, o.FKClientID, COUNT(*) As NumItems 
      FROM [Order] as o INNER JOIN
           OrderDetails as od
           ON od.FKOrderID = o.OrderID
      GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.FKClientID
     ) as o
     ON o.FKClientID = c.ClientId
GROUP BY c.ClientId, c.Name;
```

Comment: Your solution brought only those clients that had Orders made which was what I was looking for. Quick question is there any way I could add the total amount of dollars that the client has spent overall for all of his orders. I know I can do something like (od.Quantity * od.Cost) and that would give me the total spent on an order but not total spent on all orders for a client.

Comment: I managed to get the total spent on all orders by adding the following:
    SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(*) As NumOrders, SUM(o.NumItems) 
    As NumItems, Sum(o.TotalCost) AS TOTALCOST
FROM Client as c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT o.OrderID, o.FKClientID, COUNT(*) As NumItems, sum([quantity]*[cost]) AS TotalCost 
      FROM [Order] as o INNER JOIN
           OrderDetails as od
           ON od.FKOrderID = o.OrderID
      GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.FKClientID
     ) as o
     ON o.FKClientID = c.ClientId
GROUP BY c.ClientId, c.Name;

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you if you divide the task into multiple queries. I am giving the sample using Northwind database, you can test and see on it. Note that the structures and fieldnames are very similar to yours.

First create one that gets ClientId, OrderId, OrderDate and Sum of Quantity.

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, o.OrderId, o.OrderDate, sum(od.Quantity) AS Qty
FROM (Customers AS c INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId) 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS od ON o.OrderId = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, o.OrderId, o.OrderDate;
```

Save this as "OrderOfClients" (it would be saved in Queries). Next create a query that uses this one and asks for date range:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CompanyName, 
   Count(*) AS [Total Orders], 
   Sum(Qty) AS [Total Items]
FROM Customers AS c 
INNER JOIN OrdersOfClients AS co ON c.CustomerId = co.CustomerId
WHERE co.OrderDate Between [@startDate] And [@endDate]
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.CompanyName;
```

You can save this one as "OrdersOfClientsSummary" and call for your report.

PS: In my personal opinion, if you use a database other than access you would be doing yourself a big favor.